# How to SSH to a server then to another within same tab?

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel, secure-crt

I have two remotes servers (`Server_01` and `Server_02`).

My work literally is on `Server_02`. In order to access to `Server_02`, I need the first SSH to `Server_01` then another SSH to `Server_02`.

```
(machine)$ ssh Server_01
(Server_01)$ ssh Server_02
(Server_02)$ ...
```

I would like to make things easier where I could use SecureCRT or terminal tab on-click to SSH to `Server_02`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are searching for `ProxyCommand`.

```
ssh Server_02 -o ProxyCommand='ssh Server_01 -W %h:%p'
```

or even better add `Server_02` to your ~/.ssh/config

```
HOST Server_02
  user <myUsername>
  ProxyCommand ssh Server_01 -W %h:%p
```

Then you can simply use `ssh Server_02` from your local machine

Comment: I'm in a private network. I actually don't need to use the public key to ssh. I use different passwords to access to both servers. Is there any way to make the passwords configured as well in ssh config file without typing passwords?

Comment: @EricLorant No, it's not possible, because nobody wants to allow such weak security. And I can't think of any case where you really want passwords instead of keys, they are always superior (you can store them in a ssh-agent, ...)